# Save click co-ordinates to a file on the server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file, web

I am currently outputting the user click co-ordinates to the console and saving the file manually. I am trying to output these coordinates to a json file on the server which will be updated every time the user clicks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clickX;
var clickY;
  onmousemove = function(e){
    clickX = e.clientX;
    clickY = e.clientY;
    console.log('X: '+clickX+', Y: '+clickY);

    var clicks = {"x": "clickX", "y": "clickY"}
    
    $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url : "save_json.php",
      data : {
          json : JSON.stringify(clicks)
      }
  });
  }
</script>

<?php
$myFile = "clicks.json";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_GET["data"];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh)
?>
```

However I am not managing to do so with my current code.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have written but which is not working as you had hoped

Comment: Hi @SimonH, I have added my code which is currently not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few things that you're probably missing here. Firstly the ajax call makes a POST request but you're looking for the data in the `$_GET` array, so lets make the first change of the ajax request to make a GET request over here. That makes your ajax call look as follows

```
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "save_json.php",
        data : {
            json : JSON.stringify(clicks)
        }
    });
```

Similarly, another issue is in `var clicks = {"x": "clickX", "y": "clickY"}` where instead of passing `clickX` and `clickY` parameters you're passing them as strings `"clickX"` and `"clickY"`. This can be fixed by changing it to

```
var clicks = {"x": clickX, "y": clickY};
```

Lastly the event that you're using `onmousemove` records each and every single move made by the cursor and not really the clicks, based on the variable names and the question I believe you want the clicks, the event you're looking for is `onmouseup`

Now the javascript code looks as follows with the corrections made

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clickX;
var clickY;
onmouseup = function(e){
    clickX = e.clientX;
    clickY = e.clientY;
    console.log('X: '+clickX+', Y: '+clickY);

    var clicks = {"x": clickX, "y": clickY};

    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "save_json.php",
        data : {
            json : JSON.stringify(clicks)
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Now coming to the PHP part, you need to modify the script as follows, the data that you're sending gets sent as `array(1) { ["json"]=> string(17) "{"x":269,"y":125}" }` on every click, the list item you're looking for is `"json"` and not `"data"`, So making the correction to the script as follows

```
<?php
$myFile = "clicks.json";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_GET["json"];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh)
?>
```

With the right permissions on the clicks.json file, you should be able to make an entry in the file which will look as follows

```
{"x":798,"y":123}
```

and will keep getting overwritten after every click because of the `w` mode used in `fopen()`

Comment: Hi @sudheesh following some research, i found that if I change the fopen() mode to 'a' it will write to the end of the file. Thanks :)